# how to sort an array based on multiple fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array objects

```
events = [
   {
     year: "2019",
     month: "June",
     title: "title",
     desc: "desc"
   },
   {
     year: "2019",
     month: "June",
     title: "title",
     desc: "desc"
    },
    {
      year: "2019",
      month: "July",
      title: "title",
      desc: "desc"
    },
    {
      year: "2018",
      month: "June",
      title: "title",
      desc: "desc"
     },
     {
       year: "2018",
       month: "March",
       title: "title",
       desc: "desc"
     },
     {
       year: "2018",
       month: "March",
       title: "title",
       desc: "desc"
      }
    ]
```

How can I sort the array to show similar year and month, I need to use it in a react component, for example one row would show 2019 June and another 2019 July and then 2018 June and so on,

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think Typo mistake in json

Comment: what do you mean with "*similar year and month*". do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I need to get the year 2019, June to show in one row and year 2019 July in another row, and 2018 June in another row and so on, the react component is done, I just can't figure out how to sort the array to get the required values.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a custom comparator function for `.sort` to sort using month and year.

```js
const events = [
   {
     year: "2019",
     month: "June",
     title: "title",
     desc: "desc"
   },
   {
     year: "2019",
     month: "June",
     title: "title",
     desc: "desc"
    },
    {
      year: "2019",
      month: "July",
      title: "title",
      desc: "desc"
    },
    {
      year: "2018",
      month: "June",
      title: "title",
      desc: "desc"
     },
     {
       year: "2018",
       month: "March",
       title: "title",
       desc: "desc"
     },
     {
       year: "2018",
       month: "March",
       title: "title",
       desc: "desc"
      }
];

// Custom comparator function
function sortByMonthYear(a, b) {
 const keyA = `${a.month} ${a.year}`;
 const keyB = `${b.month} ${b.year}`;
 
 if (keyA.localeCompare(keyB)) {
  return -1;
 }
 else if (keyA === keyB) {
  return 0;
 }
 return 1;
}


const grouping = events.sort(sortByMonthYear);

console.log(grouping);
```

---

**Update:**

You can also group your data using [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const events = [{
    year: "2019",
    month: "June",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  },
  {
    year: "2019",
    month: "June",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  },
  {
    year: "2019",
    month: "July",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  },
  {
    year: "2018",
    month: "June",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  },
  {
    year: "2018",
    month: "March",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  },
  {
    year: "2018",
    month: "March",
    title: "title",
    desc: "desc"
  }
];

const grouping = events.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const key = `${curr.month} ${curr.year}`;
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = [curr];
  } else {
    acc[key].push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(grouping);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the previous answer you posted is what I needed

Comment: @akano1 can you please give some sample output which is needed in your question

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to all the months of the year and `flatMap` through them, within the flatMap run a filter against the original events to only return any events that share the same `month` as the current month in the iteration. 
Once you have done that, you can run a `sort` on the list to make sure the events are sorted by `year` (youngest to oldes)

```js
const MOY = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
const events = [
 {year: "2019",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2019",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2019",month: "July",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "March",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "March",title: "title",desc: "desc"}
]
    
  
const sortedByMonth = MOY.flatMap(m => events.filter(({month}) => m === month))
const sortedByYear = sortedByMonth.sort((eA, eB) => eA.year < eB.year) 
  
console.log(sortedByMonth)
console.log(sortedByYear)
```

OR if you want to chunk your events by month but order by year then do

```js
const MOY = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
const events = [
 {year: "2019",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2019",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2019",month: "July",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "June",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "March",title: "title",desc: "desc"},
 {year: "2018",month: "March",title: "title",desc: "desc"}
] 
  
const sorted = MOY.flatMap(m => (
  events
  .filter(({month}) => m === month)
  .sort((eA, eB) => eA.year < eB.year)
))
  
console.log(sorted)
```